# python string first and last char identification problem

Tags: python-3.x, string, methods, replace, uppercase

if first and last char of a string in python are the same while using replace method and uppercase on only the first char the change happens on both first and last char , why??

```
>>> text = 'standards'
>>> text = text.replace(text[0],(text[0].upper()))
>>> text
'StandardS'
```

Comment: `text[0]` is just a parameter in `replace method`,  not related to the "first char". All occurrences of the specified phrase will be replaced, if nothing else is specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.replace() function will replace all characters in string,
if you just want to change first char,you can trying divide string and conquer after, like this:

```
text=f'{text[0].upper()}{text[1:]}'
```